# How to show some input text only when filter is selected in HTML?

Tags: html, filter

I have a HTML like this:

```
 <div class="search">
     <input type="text" id="search_text" name="search_text" placeholder="Search by Name ...">
     <select>
         <option>Filter</option>
         <option>By date</option>
         <option>By size</option>
     </select>
     From: <input type="date" id="start_date" name="start_date">
     To: <input type="date" id="end_date" name="end_date">
     Size:<input type="text" id="size" name="size" placeholder="size">
     <input type="submit" onclick="return search()" value="Search">
 </div>
```

I want to show `From:` and `To:` only when `By date` is selected in filter and I want to show `"Size"` only when `By size` is selected in filter.

Comment: Use javascript/jQuery

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I made an exception and did the coding for you!

Here's a jQuery solution:

**Working example:**  http://jsfiddle.net/khRjq/

```
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" id="search_text" name="search_text" placeholder="Search by Name ...">
    <select id="selectmode">
    <option value="">Filter...</option>
    <option value="date">By date</option>
     <option value="size">By size</option>
     </select>
     <div class="bydateinputs" style="display: none">
       From: <input type="date" id="start_date" name="start_date">
       To: <input type="date" id="end_date" name="end_date">
     </div>
     <div class="bysizeinputs"  style="display: none">
        Size:<input type="text" id="size" name="size" placeholder="size">
     </div>
     <input type="submit" onclick="return search()" value="Search">
    </div>
```

JS:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(function(){
    $('#selectmode').change(function()
    {
       if ($(this).val() == 'date') 
       { 
          $('.bydateinputs').show();
          $('.bysizeinputs').hide();
       }
       if ($(this).val() == 'size') 
       { 
          $('.bydateinputs').hide();
          $('.bysizeinputs').show();
       }
    });
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, put them into a div.

Filter
        By date
         By size
    
         From: 
         To: 
         Size:

Then use jquery to handle select change event

```
$("select").change(function() {
   if($(this).text == "By date")
   {
       $("div.size").hide();
       $("div.from").show();
       $("div.to").show();
   }
   else if($(this).text == "By size")
   {
       $("div.size").show();
       $("div.from").hide();
       $("div.to").hide();
   }
   else
   {
       $("div.size").hide();
       $("div.from").hide();
       $("div.to").hide();
   }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include jQuery, you can follow [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2WdPV/) :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="search" id="searchDiv">
    <input type="text" id="search_text" name="search_text" placeholder="Search by Name ..."/>
     <select onchange="changeSearchType(this)">
         <option value="">Filter</option>
         <option value="dateinput">By date</option>
         <option value="sizeinput">By size</option>
     </select>
     <div id="dateinput" style="display:none;">
         From: <input type="date" id="start_date" name="start_date"/>
         To: <input type="date" id="end_date" name="end_date"/>
     </div>
     <div id="sizeinput" style="display:none;">
         Size:<input type="text" id="size" name="size" placeholder="size"/>
     </div>
     <input type="submit" onclick="return search()" value="Search">
 </div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
function changeSearchType(el){
    var e = el.value,
        divs = document.getElementById("searchDiv").getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(var i = 0, l = divs.length; i < l ; i++){
        divs[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(e != '') document.getElementById(e).style.display = 'block';
}
```